# How to deserialize a JSON string in .NET, when you don't have a type for it

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, view, jsonserializer

Check this URL:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/811785/questions?sort=votes

It's a URL from StackOveflow's API. The returned JSON is really complex, and I'd like to convert it into an object, so that I can use it in my ASP.NET MVC's view.

The problem is that, `JavaScriptSerializer` object's `Deserialize` method, takes a `Type` parameter as its second parameter. But the returned JSON is so complex, I don't want to create a strongly-typed object for deserializing it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in .NET 4.0, you can using dynamic

More here

http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx

And more here

http://dynamicjson.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

With [Json.NET](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Newtonsoft.Json) you can do something like this

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

string name = (string)o["Name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an extra library like JSON.NET and just work with JavaScriptSerializer.

You may consider `JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject` which will return an `Object` which is basically a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

You have to keep on **casting** to get the nested value.

See the **deserialized object** in your **Quick Watch**, then you will know what exactly you need to cast your returned `Dictionary<>`

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.Web.Script.JavascriptSerializer` which is having many `Deserialize` overloaded methods, play with it, and you will surely get what you want.